# Advance knowledge of community deletions?

Tags: support, down-votes, deletion, auto-delete

My answer to a question from 2016, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792625/is-the-sine-of-a-transcendental-angle-transcendental-or-algebraic was downvoted a couple of hours ago, and then a minute later the question was deleted by the Community user. I assume the downvote was cast in order to pave the way for the deletion, but how did the downvoter know that the Roomba was making its rounds and would be there in a minute?

Comment: FYI: see [this CRUDE post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53698430#53698430).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it is relatively safe to assume that the tasks which run daily are scheduled on the same time. (Similarly, scripts which run once a week/once a month are most likely scheduled on the same day of the week/month and on the same time or at least near the same time.)<sup>1</sup>

So if somebody noticed on a few occasions that roomba deleted questions around 03:00 AM, it is natural to expect the same time on other days.

You can have a look at a graph [showing distribution of deletion time of questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1204440/distribution-of-deleted-questions-by-minutes#graph) to see that the biggest peek is around this time. (I have purposely looked only at deletions of *questions* - not at all posts - since we're talking about [roomba](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).)

Similarly, you can see clusters of deleted questions around this time if you look at time of deletions of questions - to do this, you can use some of the queries mentioned [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/are-there-some-tools-to-follow-deletions-on-this-site/28316#28316).

It is difficult to say  whether or not some users actually prefer to downvote shortly before the scheduled task - since we do not have data on times of downvotes<sup>2</sup> and the Votes table does not contain data for deleted posts.

---

<sup>1</sup>To be more precise, the weekly roomba task actually runs 7 days since the last run, according to this answer: [What is the cause of this sudden drop in CV queue size?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209511#209567) The same answer confirms 3 AM as the scheduled time for the daily roomba task. (This answer was also quoted here: [Why does the Unanswered Question count drop on Saturdays?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25306#25307))

<sup>2</sup> Votes table and timeline only show date for votes. See: [Why is vote time missing in the SE data dump and SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933)

Comment: 3 AM in the timezone which is used in the SEDE databaze and in the timestamps - as far as I can tell, that is UTC. [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677#2678) explicitly mentions: "All timestamps are UTC, default format: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss (stored with milliseconds)." UTC is also mentioned here: [Why are the time stamps in UTC instead of localized for the client?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2941)